# ACF row to show thumbnails of recent posts

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a ACF flexible content row to display the most recent post thumbnails for a given category. However it keeps throwing a critical error and I'm not sure why.

```
<?php
$section_id = get_sub_field('section_id')
$categories = get_sub_field('categories');
$tags = get_sub_field('tags');
$postnum = get_sub_field('number_of_posts');

if (!is_array($categories)) {
  $categories = array($categories);
}
$tags = get_field('my_tags_field');
if (!is_array($tags)) {
  $tags = array($tags);
}
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
    'numberposts' => $postnum,
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
      'terms' => $categories
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'terms' => $tags
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

?>
<style>

</style>
<section class="post_row_with_thumbnails" id="<?php echo $section_id; ?>">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?>" class="project_pics">
                    <h5 class="posttitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <h6 class="postdate"><?php the_date(); ?></h6>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have tried substituting WP_Query() with get_posts() but it gives me the same critical error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's the error? There is usually a message or the error will appear in the logs. If you don't see a message, put `define( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE );` in your wp-config.php file.

Comment: I found the issue shortly after posting this, I was missing a semi-colon at the end of the first line... go figure.

Answer (score 0):

In line 2 the **;** at the end of the line, in this part:

$section_id = get_sub_field('section_id') **; THE DOT AND COMMA IS MISSING**

This is the reason for the critical error.